# Has this patent (us20040116529) been issued?

Tags: patent-pending, us20040116529

Has this patent ([us20040116529](http://www.google.com/patents/US20040116529)) been issued or is it still pending?

Comment: possible duplicate of [patent awarded or abandoned?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/9867/patent-awarded-or-abandoned)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is this patent still valid and in force?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/3971/is-this-patent-still-valid-and-in-force)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this application was abandoned in 2008.  It is not pending, and did not issue as a patent.

You can verify this here:

http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair