# Is US6796360 "Shade Tensioner" Patent still in effect?

Tags: ownership, us6796360

I want to know if the maintenance fees are current and if specialty window coverings still have claim to us6796360 patent.

Answer (score 1):

[US6796360](https://www.google.com/patents/US6796360?pg=PA8&dq=6796360) was filed and has a priority date of: **Feb 25, 2003**  The original life of the patent would have been 20 years from Feb 25, 2003 or **Feb 25, 2023**

The first claim of '360 is:

> A tension shade comprising:
>
> 1. A headrail supporting a window covering;
> 2. A bottom rail operatively connected to the window covering;
>      at least one tension cord extending from the headrail and operatively connected to the bottom rail;
> 3. At least one tensioner connected to the tension cord and configured to be releasably secured to a structure;
>      the tensioner including...
>
>    - a first component having an engagement surface and
>    - a second component having a second engagement surface;
>    - a portion of the first component interfering with a portion of the second component inhibiting the first and second components from separating,
>    - the first and second components having a first position wherein the first engagement surface and the second engagement surface are spaced apart a predetermined distance sufficient to frictionally engage a portion of the tension cord,
>    - the first component being movable within the second component from the first position to a second fully engaged position clamping the tension cord between the first and second engagement surfaces.

According to [Public Pair](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/3971/is-this-patent-still-valid-and-in-force/3972#3972) the patent was issued **May 20, 2004**.  It **expired** due to non-payment of maintenance fees on **Oct, 27, 2008**.  So long as it is expired **the patent is no longer current and is no longer in force**.

[image]

Which can also be seen on [Google Patents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cSHH.png):

[image]

It is not clear what is meant by "if speciality window coverings still have claim to us6796360 patent".  However, if the question is whether a third party should worry about the owner of the '360 preventing the manufacture or sale of products which infringe the '360 patent, the answer is **NO** (unless and until the patent is revived).

I'll leave it to other participants on [Ask Patents](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request?sort=active&pagesize=25) to opine on whether the '360 patent could in principle be revived by payment of the overdue maintenance fees 5 years after patent has expired.