# Contact info for Marcus Dominic Gonzalez

Tags: us20110056000

I've searched up and down for the patent owners contact info but found nothing. How do I reach out to Marcus Dominic Gonzalez  the patent owner to discuss the patent?

Answer (score 1):

[US20110056000](http://www.google.com/patents/us20110056000) is a **Patent Application**, not an issued patent.  It received a **Final Rejection** on Oct 12, 2012.  It was subsequently abandoned by the applicant for failure to respond to the **Final Rejection** on June 2, 2013.

An interesting public resource and the way any user can see all of this information is through [Public Pair](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair).

A good primer on [using Public Pair can be found in this answer](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/3972/1767)

The current status of US20110056000 can be seen here.  Note the status **"Abandoned - Failure to Respond to an Office Action"**:

[image: Status of US20110056000]

In case you are still interested in getting in touch with the applicant you can see his contact information on the applicant information form submitted with the patent application in September, 2010.

[image: Information about the Applicant of US20110056000]