# Electronic Marketplace - Patent Application - PRIOR ART REQUEST

Tags: patentability, prior-art-request, us20120030046

10 minutes of your time can help narrow US patent applications before they become patents.  [Follow @askpatents](https://twitter.com/AskPatents) on twitter to help.

Patent Application: [US 20120030046 A1](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120030046)

Title: **Buying and Selling Portions of a Composite good in an Electronic Marketplace**

Priority Date: Seeking **public disclosure** of Prior Art prior to **Jul 27, 2010**

---

System and Method for Buying and Selling Portions of a Composite good in an Electronic Marketplace - Described herein is an improved system and method for buying and selling portions of a composite good in an electronic marketplace. One method and system comprise communicating to a buyer a first good post associated with a seller, and communicating to a seller a “want to buy” post from the buyer, wherein the “want to buy” post is for a second good different from, but associated with, the first good. Another system and method comprise displaying online a want to buy post from a buyer, for a first good, and communicating to a buyer a seller offer for a second good, associated with the first good.

First claim:

> 1. A method for buying and selling a portion of a composite good in an electronic marketplace comprising:
>
>    - providing an application operable by a buyer and a seller over a network;
>    - receiving a want-to-sell post for a composite good by said seller using said application over said network;
>    - writing said want-to-sell post to a first memory space accessible to buyer over said network;
>    - receiving a want-to-buy post for a portion of said composite good by said buyer using said application over said network; and
>    - writing said want-to-buy post to a second memory space accessible to said seller over said network.

---

**NOTE** according to [Public Pair](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/3972/1767) this patent received a **Final Rejection** on 3/13/2013. It is possible for the applicant to file a [Request for Continued Examination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuing_patent_application#Request_for_continued_examination) and revise the claims.

Under the AIA it appears not to be possible to submit prior art under the pre-grant process used by Ask Patents for this application.  Prior art which is found below would need to submitted under the six-month post-grant process.

*What is good prior art? Please see our [FAQ](https://patents.stackexchange.com/faq#prior-art).*

*Want to help? Please vote or comment on submissions below. We welcome you to [post your own request for prior art](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prior-art-request+pre-grant) on other questionable US Patent Applications.*

Comment: [Original Patent PDF link](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pdfs/US20120030046.pdf)

Comment: It helps a lot if you provide a date that prior-art has to be, well, prior to.

Comment: I don't know much about the patent system and prior art requirements, but the PDF says "Filed: Jul. 27, 2010" and "Pub. Date: Feb. 2, 2012".

Comment: [Google Patents: US20120030046](http://www.google.com/patents/US20120030046)

Comment: Priority Date: Jul 27, 2010

Comment: As I understand it, the claim is: in a system where both buyers and sellers are allowed to post, if a seller posts he's selling an iPhone (for eg.) and the buyer posts she wants an iPhone cover, the system intimates the seller about the buy request, and if he starts selling an iPhone cover, intimates the buyer. Is this about correct? And why the does the 4th claim say "The method of claim 1 Wherein the composite good is a second portion of a second composite good." Why "second portion" specifically?

Answer (score 1):

I think he's saying:

METHOD ONE
Seller: 'I have a car for sale'
Buyer: 'I want to buy a tire'

METHOD TWO
Buyer: 'I want to buy a tire'
Seller: 'I have a car for sale'

This is patentable?

Comment: I think it's more like: Seller: I have a parts cars and I'm selling the hood for $100. Buyer: I need the fender. Seller: Ok I am selling the fender too for $50.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @MattGupta's interpretation, and specifically the claim seems to be for the site intimating the seller about the request for a fender, and later intimating the buyer about the availability of a fender (if the seller makes a post for that).

Comment: Thanks MattGupta now it makes sense. This does sound like craigslist, or any classified ad in any newspaper where the complete list of goods for sale are not named (i.e. Garage Sale).

Comment: I am not an attorney, but I would like to protest this patent because it doesn't seem like this very fundamental process should be patentable. What would be the process for protesting formally to the US Patent Office?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a lot like Craigslist to me.

Comment: or any classified ad where the particular goods sold are not all named