# Is Patent US4820036 expired?

Tags: patentability, patent-lifetime, us4820036

[This patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US4820036?dq=US4820036) says it is lapsed. Was this patent actually issued? It says failure to pay fees.  I looked it up on the US Patent website and it said it could not be found. Can anyone help me here?

Title: Headband for retention of glasses
Patent:  [US4820036 A](https://www.google.com/patents/US4820036?dq=US4820036)

Comment: Will, Can you provide a patent number and resubmit?  As written there isn't enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Sure! This is what it has listed.  US4820036 A

Answer (score 1):

US4820036 is lapsed and expired.  The best place to look this up is on [Google Patents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE6D1.png):

[image]

[Patent lifetime in US](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_of_patent_in_the_United_States) prior to 1995 was generally 17 years from date of issuance (after 1995 is generally 20 years from the priority date, or the date of the earliest application to which priority is claimed).

Patent US4820036 was issued in 1989 so it would have **fallen into the public domain in 2006**

Owners of US Patents are required to pay maintenance fees during the term of the patent or the patent lapses before the end of its term.  It looks like this patent lapsed before the end of its term.

You can also look up more detail about the file history for this patent on [Public PAIR](http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair)
[image]

For more information overall on how to determine remaining patent life for a US Patent see this question: [Patent Lifetime and PAIR](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/3972/1767)