# Where can I contact the inventor of US20060081742A1, Type D1 Guardrail Reflector?

Tags: us20060081742

I have installed items similar to the D1 reflectors described in [US2006081742](https://www.google.com/patents/US20060081742).  I believe I have spotted an opportunity to improve the invention described in this patent application. Can anyone please help me to get hold off the inventor Mr Garcia Guadalupe?

Answer (score 2):

[US2006081742](https://www.google.com/patents/US20060081742) is a Patent application.  The best way to find information about a US patent application or an issued US patent is on Google Patents.  The second best way is through the [Public PAIR](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/3972/1767) system of the USPTO.

US2006081742 was rejected by the USPTO in 2007 and subsequently abandoned. The inventor was Guadalupe Garcia and he used an IP service called [Lumen IP](http://lumen.com/), which is located in Palo Alto, California and is frequently used by nearby Stanford University:

[image]

The patent was subsequently assigned to:

> Worldwide Safety, Inc
>
> 648 46th Street
>
> Sacramento, CA 95819

[image]

Worldwide Safety, Inc. does not appear to have a website.  The address appears to be a home address. The best way to reach the inventor is probably through [Lumen IP](http://lumen.com/), which may still have contact information and an email address for the inventor. The second best way is to look through the [other patent applications Guadalupe Garcia has filed at the USPTO](https://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=pts&hl=en&q=ininventor:%22Guadalupe+Garcia%22)  It appears the inventor may now live in Santa Monica, California.

[image]