# How to find out if a patent has been awarded or abandoned?

Tags: patent-pending

Has this patent been awarded or is the patent still pending? It shows in the database as pending, but that was back in 2009. If the idea was abandoned, would the patent still be listed as pending?

Comment: Check the USPTO PAIR database http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair for the status

Answer (score 3):

If you check on the USPTO's public PAIR system, you can see the status of a published application. If the application has been abandoned, the status should say, for example: "Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action."

http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair

Comment: Good answer. I'd would add that most of the information in google's database is created directly from the actual published patent document. Published documents are not live things that change after being published. As I mention in another post, the 2003 published phone book will never reflect your address change made in 2005. Google could look up the up-to-date status in "live" databases at the USPTO and also provide that to supplement the data taken from the "dead" publication.